# Помогите исправить ошибку: use of undeclared identifier 'n'

Tags: c++, c, cs50

Помогите исправить ошибку в программе по подсчету кол. монет. Когда начинаю компилировать вылетает ошибка: 
use of undeclared identifier 'n'
В программировании я полный новичок, поэтому не исключено, что весь мой код одна сплошная ошибка, но насколько я понял компилятор не видит где описывается n, хотя я описал ее в 15 строке

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float GetMyFloat();
int main(void)
{
    printf("Сдача: ");
    float i = GetMyFloat();

    float a = 0.25;
    float b = 0.10;
    float c = 0.05;
    float d = 0.01;

    for (float n = 0; n>0.0; n=n+1)
    {
      if (i>=a)
      {
        i = i-a;
      }
      else if(i>=b)
      {
        i = i-b;
      }
      else if (i>=c)
      {
        i = i-c;
      }
      else if (i>=d)
      {
        i = i-d;
      }

    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%i\n", n);

}

float GetMyFloat(void)
{
    float i;
    do
    {

      i = get_float();
      while (i<1)
      {
          printf ("Число должно быть больше 0!\n");
          printf("Сдача: ");
          i = get_float();
      }
    }
      while (i<1);
      return i;
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать переменную `n` вне зоны ее существования.

Comment: Прежде чем что-то писать почитайте сначала про области видимости

Comment: Цикл не будет выполнен ни разу, потому что условие продолжения цикла с самого начала не выполняется.

Comment: Прежде чем предложить правки, неплохо понять логику, чего надо получить, и из чего расчитывается здача, и почему столько раз.. И монеты по логике целое число..

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь вывести n все зоны ее существования, обьявите переменную выше попробуйте данный код (код написан без компилятора могут быть ошибки) :)
почитайте еще про [область видимости](http://cppstudio.com/post/415/)

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
float GetMyFloat();
int main(void)
{
    cout << "Сдача: ";
    float i = GetMyFloat();

    float a = 0.25;
    float b = 0.10;
    float c = 0.05;
    float d = 0.01;
    float n = 0;

    for (n>=0.0; n++)
    {
      if (i>=a)
      {
        i = i-a;
      }
      else if(i>=b)
      {
        i = i-b;
      }
      else if (i>=c)
      {
        i = i-c;
      }
      else if (i>=d)
      {
        i = i-d;
      }

    }
    cout << "\n" << "%i\n" << n;

}

float GetMyFloat(void)
{
    float i;
    do
    {

      i = get_float();
      while (i<1)
      {
          printf ("Число должно быть больше 0!\n");
          printf("Сдача: ");
          i = get_float();
      }
    }
      while (i<1);
      return i;
}
```

Comment: Ваша поправка для цикла превратило его из невыполняющегося в бесконечный.

Comment: @freim _код написан без компилятора могут быть ошибки_

Comment: :) разные стороны одной медали